# What are the questions starting with "How long" that correspond to "I have three weeks to learn English" & "I have to learn English for three weeks"?

Tags: difference, questions, interrogatives, wh-questions

What will be the questions that start with "How long..." for these two following sentences?

> I have three weeks to learn English.
> I have to learn English for three weeks.

The only question that pop up in my mind is: How long do I have to learn English?
And I don't know which sentence suits this above question. Also what will be the question for the other one?

Comment: I think part of the problem comes from the fact that "I have to learn English for three weeks" is a strange, slightly non-fluent sentence.  Do you mean that you have to spend three weeks studying English?

Comment: Also note that these sentences don't mean the same thing: the first speaks of a deadline for learning English (whatever that means), and the second doesn't say anything about a goal, just that three weeks have to be spent learning.

Comment: Learn question forms. For example: What are the questions that start with How Long. Also, the only question that pop**s** up etc.

Answer (score 1):

The first example has already been answered by OP in the question:

> Q. How long do you have to learn English?
> A. I have three weeks to learn English.

The second example could be

> Q. How long will you be learning English for?
> A. I have to learn English for three weeks.

Some people won't like the 'for' at the end of the sentence and might prefer

> Q. For how long will you be learning English?
> A. I have to learn English for three weeks.

Comment: Is there any way to include that modal verb 'have to'  in question? Because I'm trying to make a question including the modal verb: how long do i have to learn English. Again it results the same. That's so confusing.

Comment: Then it would be the same (perhaps ambiguous) question as the first. There are various scenarios: You must learn English in only three weeks; you must attend the first three weeks of an English course; the lessons only last for three weeks...

Comment: @Indumathi "have to do something" is **not a modal verb**.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I **have** three weeks to learn English.
> 2. I **have to** learn English for three weeks.

The key words are bolded for clarity.

OP's suggested question suits answer (1):

> How long do I **have** to learn English?

The verb *have* here means **to possess**.

In answer (2), *have to* is [an idiom used to say that something is required or necessary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20to), or **need to**.

We could modify the question used for the other answer by adding **for** at the end:

> How long do I **have to** (or **need to**) learn English **for**?